# Optimizing MySQL SELECT query with subqueries

Tags: mysql

Hi is it possible to optimize the SELECT query below? The query itself is working but when we are querying large data we are encountering a message in php which is "Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded". I reduced the columns in the query up to `Topping3` but I am querying up to `Topping15` column.

```
SELECT 
    itemID,
    itemName,
    Topping1,
    (SELECT DISTINCT Description FROM items WHERE PLU = a.Topping1 AND ClientID = 1679) AS Top1_desc,
    Topping2,
    (SELECT DISTINCT Description FROM items WHERE PLU = a.Topping2 AND ClientID = 1679) AS Top2_desc,
    Topping3,
    (SELECT DISTINCT Description FROM items WHERE PLU = a.Topping2 AND ClientID = 1679) AS Top3_desc,
FROM
    items a
WHERE
    ...
```

Current data on `items` table

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| itemID | itemName | Description | Topping1 | Topping2 | Topping3 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|    1   |   HAM1   |  Hamburger  |   ONI1   |   TOMO1  |          |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|    2   |   ONI1   |    Onion    |          |          |          |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|    3   |   TOMO1  |   Tomato    |          |          |          |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

and this is the expected result

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| itemID | itemName | Description | Topping1 | Top1_desc | Topping2 | Top2_desc | Topping3 | Top3_desc |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    1   |   HAM1   |  Hamburger  |   ONI1   |   Onion   |   TOMO1  |  Tomato   |          |          |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    2   |   ONI1   |    Onion    |          |           |          |           |          |          |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    3   |   TOMO1  |   Tomato    |          |           |          |           |          |          |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be fast, unless there are a lot of entries with the same client ID. You could add `LIMIT 1` after all subqueries, i.e.: `(SELECT DISTINCT Description FROM items WHERE PLU = a.Topping1 AND ClientID = 1679 LIMIT 1)` etc.

I suspect however that it is an index problem. Are the fields ClientID and PLU indexed?

**EDIT:** Alternative for your query:

```
SELECT 
    itemID,
    itemName,
    Topping1,
    t1.Description AS Top1_desc,
    Topping2,
    t2.Description AS Top2_desc,
    Topping3,
    t3.Description AS Top3_desc,
FROM
    items a
LEFT JOIN
    items t1 ON t1.PLU=a.Topping1 AND t1.ClientID = 1679
LEFT JOIN
    items t2 ON t2.PLU=a.Topping2 AND t2.ClientID = 1679
LEFT JOIN
    items t3 ON t3.PLU=a.Topping3 AND t3.ClientID = 1679
WHERE
    ...
GROUP BY
    a.itemID
```

Fields `itemID`, `PLU` and `ClientID` need indexes.

Comment: Hi, yes both the ClientID and PLU are indexed. We'll try to add `LIMIT 1` to the subqueries.

Comment: As I don't feel the LIMIT will help I added an additional way to write your query. Joins are usually faster than subqueries.